# For folder in dir, enter it and delete files if condition is met

Tags: python, subdirectory

My dir looks something like this:

```
dir
|_folder1
  |_file1.py
  |_file2.png
|_folder2
  |_file1.py
  |_file2.png
|_etc..
```

I want to enter each folder and delete all files that don't have `.py` in their name, only part of the problem I don't know how to solve its how to know if the file is a folder and to enter it if is.

I tried with `listdir()` and asked for the type of each element in that list, but all were `string`, probably because it's just a list of names.

Comment: You'll have to walk the directory to determine all the files under `dir` and save them (e.g. a list). Once populated, you can remove the Python files using a filter or generator expression.

Comment: For walking folders/files, I like to use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob). Use it to find all files in the folders you want, then filter the results.

Comment: You can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to determine the files and folders in the directory tree starting at `dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should spend time to make this function more efficient. However, it will do what you want.

```
import os

def deleteNonPyFiles(parent_dir):
    no_delete_kw = '.py'
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(parent_dir):
        for file in filenames:
            if no_delete_kw not in file:
                os.remove(f'{dirpath}/{file}')
   
deleteNonPyFiles('C:/User/mydirpath')
```

Comment: Perhaps use `os.path.splitext()` to test the file extension.

Comment: What do you mean? I am using the variable no_delete_kw to identify if the file extension is of the type tat we do not want to delete

Comment: Sure.  However, what if the filename is `modules.py.tar`; and user is expecting it to be deleted?

Comment: The question says they don't want files with `.py` in it to be deleted. So why would the user expected `modules.py.tar` to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk(...)` conveniently steps through all folders and sub-folders under the supplied folder and returns a list of all files within each folder.  You can then reconstruct the full path to the file and ignore any that end in `.py`.

You can try:

```py
import os

for dir_path, _, file_names in os.walk('/path/to/your/parent/directory'):
    for delete_me in [os.path.join(dir_path, fname) for fname in file_names if not fname.endswith('.py')]:
        print(f'REMOVING: {delete_me}')
        os.remove(delete_me)
```

Comment: Perhaps use `os.path.splitext()` to test the file extension.

Comment: Sure that's fine.  I could also choose to use the `pathlib` library and just get the extension straight away with [PurePath.suffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) if I wanted to be clever about it. ;)  Point is that there are a few things that can be done based on personal preference.  But they don't really make the answer any better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

```
from os import walk, remove

def get_filenames(path):
    filenames = next(walk(path), (None, None, []))[2]
    return filenames

def delete_files_without_key(path, key):
    child_dirs = next(walk(path))[1]
    for dir in child_dirs:
        files = get_filenames(f"{path}/{dir}")
        for file in files:
            if key not in file:
                remove(f"{path}/{dir}/{file}")


delete_files_without_key('/path/to/parent/directory', key=".py")
```